# Caching in spark before diverging the flow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have a basic question regarding working with Spark DataFrame.

Consider the following piece of pseudo code:

```
val df1 = // Lazy Read from csv and create dataframe
val df2 = // Filter df1 on some condition
val df3 = // Group by on df2 on certain columns
val df4 = // Join df3 with some other df

val subdf1 = // All records from df4 where id < 0
val subdf2 =  // All records from df4 where id > 0

* Then some more operations on subdf1 and subdf2 which won't trigger spark evaluation yet*

// Write out subdf1
// Write out subdf2
```

Suppose I start of with main dataframe `df1`(which I lazy read from the CSV), do some operations on this dataframe (filter, groupby, join) and then comes a point where I split this datframe based on a condition (for eg, id > 0 and id < 0). Then I further proceed to operate on these sub dataframes(let us name these `subdf1, subdf2`) and ultimately write out both the sub dataframes.

Notice that the `write` function is the only command that triggers the spark evaluation and rest of the functions(filter, groupby, join) result in lazy evaluations.

Now when I write out `subdf1`, I am clear that lazy evaluation kicks in and all the statements are evaluated starting from reading of CSV to create df1.

My question comes when we start writing out `subdf2`. Does spark understand the divergence in code at `df4` and store this dataframe when command for writing out `subdf1` was encountered? Or will it again start from the first line of creating `df1` and re-evaluate all the intermediary dataframes?
If so, is it a good idea to `cache` the dataframe `df4`(Assuming I have sufficient memory)?

I'm using scala spark if that matters.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spark cannot infer that from your code. It will start all over again. To confirm this, you can do `subdf1.explain()` and `subdf2.explain()` and you should see that both dataframes have query plans that start right from the beginning where `df1` was read.

So you're right that you should cache `df4` to avoid redoing all the computations starting from `df1`, if you have enough memory. And of course, remember to unpersist by doing `df4.unpersist()` at the end if you no longer need `df4` for any further computations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. As for ```df4.unpersist()```, do you think it is required for the above pseudocode? Assuming the code ends after writing two sub dfs?

Comment: I think it's still a good habit to unpersist, even if your code ends.